# Find matching values in two pandas dataframes and return a value from the matching row

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, concatenation

It was difficult to word this question in a way that was clear and precise, so hopefully the below helps to shed more light on my problem.

I have two pandas dataframes, simplified for this example, they are:

```
df1 = 
'CENSUS_ID'  
60014001001
60014002001

df2 = 
'GEO_ID'    'MED_INCOME'
60014001001   177417
60014002001   166313
60014002002   132400
60014003001   161964
```

I want to add a column to df1 called 'MED_INCOME' by finding the matching GEO_ID in df2 and returning the 'MED_INCOME' value. While these dataframes are simplified, the actual len of df1 is potentially hundreds of rows long and the len of df2 is tens of thousands of rows long. So, while I could easily set this up to iterate through to find the matches, it is less than ideal as it is very slow. I would like to use the pandas apply() as it seems to be a lot faster, or perhaps there is another solution, but I'm having difficulty working out the logic, as there's still a lot of pandas 'tricks' that I am new to or unaware of. Perhaps it's easier to remove the non-matching columns from df2, rather than adding to df1, but I just don't know. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do a left merge (left outer join). This will keep all of the observations in `df1` while matching it with `GEO_ID` in `df2`:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='CENSUS_ID', right_on='GEO_ID', how='left')
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't really understand how to use the merge methods before, so this was a good way to introduce me to it.